# Vanilla forum "SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host."

Tags: email, smtp, phpmailer

Since I upgraded my production site (Linux, Apache) from Vanilla 2.2.1 on PHP 5.5 to Vanilla 2.3.1 on PHP 7.0, my site cannot send emails - failing with the message "SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host."

My settings are:

- SMTP Host: smtp.gmail.com
- SMTP User: [my email]
- SMTP Password: [my password]
- SMTP Port: 465
- SMTP Security: SSL

I read many similar questions on SO and tried the following:

- Confirm OpenSSL is enabled
- Confirm with the hosting provider that port 465 is not blocked on their firewall
- Telnet test on the hosting server gives this:

  ```
  $ telnet smtp.gmail.com 465
  Trying 108.177.97.108...
  Connected to smtp.gmail.com.
  Escape character is '^]'.
  Connection closed by foreign host.
  ```
- Switching to a different hosting server (same provider) with PHP 7.0, but same error

Not sure if this will be useful information, but when I try TLS with port 587 it gives another error - "Language string failed to load: tls"

My local test site with Vanilla 2.3.1 on PHP 7.0 (Windows, IIS), an identical copy of the production, can send emails without problem with the above SSL settings.

Is there anything else I can try? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: If you're getting a "Language string failed to load" error, it means you're using a really ancient version of PHPMailer. [Get the latest](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer), and base your code on the gmail example provided with PHPMailer.

Comment: @Synchro Thank you for your reply. I checked the version and you're right. I use Vanilla forum as-is and am not knowledgeable about PHP, but I'll see if I can get it working with the newer version. Thanks again!